# Does Windows 7 Bitlocker support VHD drives

Tags: windows-7, bitlocker, vhd

I'm trying to decide whether to upgrade my Windows 7 installation to either a better version of Windows 7, or to Windows 8. The decision rests on support for a specific feature.

I'm aware that Bitlocker is not available in Windows 7 Professional, but the Ultimate and Enterprise editions have it installed.

In Windows 8/Server 2012 it is possible to create a VHD file using the Disk Management tool and to mount the VHD as a drive and have the drive encrypted using Bitlocker.

Is this supported in Windows 7 Ultimate/Enterprise editions? Will Bitlocker encrypted VHD containers created in Win8 be mountable in Windows 7 Ultimate/Enterprise editions?

Answer (score -1):

Due to the lack of response, I installed a VM and tested this myself.

The scenario described in the question is indeed supported in Windows 7 Ultimate edition. Bitlocker encrypted VHD files created in Windows 8/Server 2012 can be used in Windows 7 Ultimate edition.